# ComponentDidMount called multiple times when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component something like this:

```js
class TeamIndividualView extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .all([axios.get(URL), axios.options(URL)])
      .then(
        axios.spread((memberRes, optionsRes) => {
          // do something
        })
      )
  }
}
```

This component is rendered when I visit the Route (react-router)

```js
<Route
  exact
  path={`${urlAppAlumni()}/:handle`}
  render={props => <TeamIndividualView {...props} isActive={false} />}
/>
```

I can get here to this page via 2 methods:

1. By clicking and following some links (used `<Link to="dfvfd/" />`) to get here.
2. By directly hitting the URL - `/maintainer_site/team/dfvfd/`. (`urlAppAlumni()` = `/maintainer_site/team/`)

When I go to the page using the 2nd method, I see that my component is mounting multiple times (thrice most of the time) since it sends 6 API requests to my backend (3 GET + 3 OPTIONS). Even if I log something in the console, it gets printed thrice. Meanwhile, method 1 works fine.

The code is open-sourced. One can find the component here - https://github.com/IMGIITRoorkee/omniport-frontend-maintainer-site/blob/master/src/components/team-individual-view.js

Comment: Are you setting the `state` ? That could be the reason

Comment: Yes, I am setting the `state` when the promise in Axios call is fulfilled.

Comment: @DominikMatis But, the same component is being mounted when I go there by clicking links. And in that case, I get the desired results.

Comment: Maybe this can be an issue because of the loading of the whole page, as you need to load full page in method 2

Comment: Could you try it with a dummy component to see if it also gets mounted twice to see if the issue is caused by the component or routing logic.

Comment: @CagataySel it works fine here - https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-currying-0y1eo. I can't seem to figure out the exact issue.

Comment: @DominikMatis yeah, there is an issue. I need help in finding that. Can you guess any probable bug?

Comment: It is a wild guess but there might be a problem with your nested routing logic. Router might be matching "/maintainer_site/team/dfvfd"  path twice if you have routing in your "/maintainer_site/team" page too. Try to use a direct path such as "/dfvfd".

Comment: I'd try to look for rendering in react devtools, but probably you have some match for routes

Comment: What does the path resolve to [here](https://github.com/IMGIITRoorkee/omniport-frontend-maintainer-site/blob/master/src/components/app.js#L101) on line 101?

Comment: You can check all the URLs here https://github.com/IMGIITRoorkee/omniport-frontend-maintainer-site/blob/master/src/urls.js#L21 @DrewReese

Comment: @CagataySel probably, but I would prefer if this can be done without using such a direct path.